# How to remove duplicate arithmetic operators using regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

this is my input string in react : `4-+3-4`
I want to check `onChange()` function when a duplicate arithmetic entered, like this `-+` replace last operator with first one, how can i detect that on change function?
input should change on change to `4+3-4`
I tried and tested but failed
This is my regex for finding operators and last operator `/[+*\/-]/g` `/[+*\/-]$/g`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"replace last operator with first one"*? I would think that when you replace the last operator, it would be gone. Is in your example, `+` the "last operator"? If yes, and it got replaced "with first one", how come your desired output still has the `+`?

Comment: this is a wrong input, open up your windows calculator and try to enter two different arithmetic operators, if your input is an operator while your last character was an operator too, your input will be replaced with that, am I right?

Comment: So you are now saying you want the previous operator to be replaced with the last. Seems the opposite from how you wrote it in the question.

Comment: yeah cause my english sux :D sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a regex replace approach:

```js
var input = "4-+3-4";
var output = input.replace(/[*/+-]+([*/+-])/g, "$1");
console.log(output);
```

This approaches matches two or more successive arithmetic operators, capturing the final one.  It then replaces with just this final operator.

Comment: @Skinny While I'm not a JavaScript expert, you could call this replacement inside the on change or keypress event.  That is, you do this operator cleanup every time the input changes.

Comment: true that, but please test snippet with this input too `"4++3-4"`, does still work for you?

Comment: I fixed this issue with this regex `/[+*\/-]+([+*\/-])/g, "$1"` thank u for helping me out )

Comment: @Skinny The character class `[*/+-]` is completely valid and the forward slash does not need to be escaped.